# 3d max integration with c++, Cal3D where to start?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

okay i'm making a game using c++ (for the engine) and openGL, now i've had lots of trouble using cal3d library for importing my 3d max models into my c++ project,

as a matter of fact i dunno where to even start, i can't find any decent guide and their documentation is pure shit really. i've been searching and trying stuff in this for over a month, but i don't even understand the file structure it uses so far :S

i really need some help, r there any other libraries? any decent guide i can use? i'm stuck

thnx alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than write your own exporter, consider using one of the built-in exporters for FBX, COLLADA, Crosswalk (.XSI), the Quake/Doom3 .MD3/.MD4 format, or even OBJ. It'll be much easier to parse the resulting file format on your end than to write and maintain a brand-new exporter.

Answer (score 1):

Max is a complete pain for any kind of scripting or plugin. I'd suggest using maya instead if at all possible. You'll get better results for animation and rigging, too. I know it's not a direct answer to your question but part of the problem is the info for stuff like this is not easy to come by.